# Is there a way to make PuTTY try ~/.ssh/id_rsa by default without having to save every connection?

Tags: putty, private-key

I use the same public key for many servers and I hate having to set up saved connection configurations for each and every one of them.

OpenSSH clients automatically search for a specific key path in your home directory.

Is there a way to make PuTTY do the same by default?

Comment: PuTTY on Windows? Or *nix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options:

- Save you private key to ["Default Settings"](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-saving);
- Even better, use [Pageant authentication agent](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter9.html).